# Need help in displaying all the columns, there is missing data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, console, csv

I am trying to sort a txt file through 3rd column in c#. I can see 4 rows beneath my columns but the text file contains a lot more rows. I also need to get one more functionality working and that is removing duplicate data from the display. {If data in the first and second column is the same as another row then remove one instance from the display. data is case sensitive i.e. broc is not the same as BRoc}. Help appreciated. My code is as follows. Please note that the txt file is a TSV and not a CSV.

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var records = (from l in File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\data\542112107\Desktop\project 1\Project1\Project1\bin\Debug\instance_test.txt")
                           let pieces = l.Split('\t')
                           select new { Col1 = pieces[0], Col2 = pieces[1], Col3 = pieces[2], Col4 = pieces[3] })



                .Skip(1)


                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(c => c.Col3);

            for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
            {

            } foreach (var r in records)
            { Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2},{3}", r.Col1, r.Col2, r.Col3, r.Col4); }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the sample input:(\n is new line)

```
Heading 1   Heading 2     Heading3    Heading 4

ascvad3124        adfdasfData            asasffasf       adsfasfasdf 
asf123134Data      dasfasdfdasfData        Dasfasfata      asdfasdfadsf
123123fData       asdfdasfsData        asdfasdfasdf          sadvsdfdaf
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input (with just a few lines) and the output of running the code with that input, with an explanation of how it's wrong?

Comment: edited the question for the input. Output is here:
heading 1 heading2 heading3 heading4 \n
asd         asf      asdfas  asdf   \n
asd         asf      asdfas  asdf   \n
asd         asf      asdfas  asdf   \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first issue is that you're not ordering on the third column's value; you're ordering on the second letter of the third column's value.  Change `c.Col3[1]` to just `c.Col3` when ordering to actually order on the third column.

Another issue is that you're grouping on the concatenation of all of the fields; this isn't particularly safe.  Here "ab", "c", "d", "e" will be considered equal to "a", "bc", "d", "e".  You can just call `Distinct` instead of `GroupBy`.  Anonymous objects properly override `Equals` an `GetHashCode` to be based on the underlying properties, not the reference, so this will work just fine.

Next, You can use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` to lazily read in the lines, instead of eagerly loading in all of the lines when you are only going to go and process the data lazily anyway.

Comment: The reason the code had c.Col3[1] is because it sorts the column header as well. Doing this the sorting process starts from the second column, leaving the header column intact.

Comment: can you give me a sample code of what you are trying to do. I am a noob currently. Wont stay that way for long. ;) and i will use ReadLines for the code. Appreciate the input brother!

Comment: @user1063280 But you're not getting the second row.  As I said, you're getting the second character of that string, which is clearly not what you want.  For dealing with the header row you should probably just skip it (Use `Skip(1)` and then add the headers back in later if you need them.

Comment: @user1063280 I have told you exactly what you need to change.  Adding in all of the code that won't change is just wasting space.

Comment: if I add distinct, it gives out an error saying cannot convert lambda expression to type. and I tested out your theory that it is sorting from the second char, but its not according to my output.

Comment: @user1063280 You don't need to provide any lambda at all to `Distinct`, call it with the parameterless overload.  And yes, you are ordering on the second character of the third column.  You're mis-reading your output if you think otherwise.

Comment: my bad brother, you were right, I was misreading the output. Can you please update the code and post it. I will vote you for the answer as I do not understand some terms. But, I will learn and understand how the code is working

Comment: @user1063280 I have described exactly what you need to fix, and it even seems that you were able to apply those fixes without any problems.  Posing the full code is a waste of time and space for everyone.

Comment: I was not able to apply the fixes. getting errors, maybe its because I am using visual studio 2008 and older frameworks. You posting 4 lines of code is unlikely to waste space and I will delete all my useless comments to make up for it. Help a friend out man

Comment: @user1063280 What errors are you getting, if you're getting errors?

Comment: Error 1 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLines' 
.Skip<records[1]>; -> syntax is not valid.

Comment: .Distinct<c.Col3>  invalid syntax

Comment: @user1063280 You're using a version before `ReadLines` was added, you'll need to skip that bit of advice until you upgrade, or write your own `ReadLines` method.  `Skip` should be written as simply `Skip(1)`.  `Distinct` should be written as `Distinct()`.  Neither should have generic arguments supplied.

Comment: using .netframework 3.5 which has different syntax requirements

Comment: @user1063280 The only aspect of this answer that is different for 3.5 from later versions is that you don't have a `ReadLines`.  The rest is all the same.

Comment: @user1063280 Where are you calling `Skip`?

Comment: dont have enough reputation to post images, tried to put up screenshots

Comment: distinct is asking for different syntax as well

Comment: @user1063280 Update the code in your question to what you're using.

Comment: Updated the question. Also now the skip is working, pretty weird I would say, did not make any changes. How should I get distinct working which is case sensitive and acts as making the combination of two columns distinct?

Comment: @user1063280 I said that you should replace the `GroupBy` with `Distinct`.  You still have `GroupBy` there.  You should also remove the second `Select` now that you're not grouping the items.

Comment: if I replace the groupby "Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type "

Comment: @user1063280 All you need to do is leave the `Skip`, `Distinct`, and `OrderBy` methods exactly as you have them, removing the other query operators.  There won't be any compiler errors if you do that.

Comment: look at the edited code, I have that but the distinct operator wont do its job

Comment: @user1063280 It's giving you distinct rows, which is its job.

Comment: oh okay, makes sense, how do I go about the union of first and 3rd columns distinct? appreciate the help bro. I am learning a lot out of you

Comment: marked your answer, will be a great help if you solve my last problem. Thanks man

Comment: @user1063280 That's different from what you were doing before; before you were grouping on all four values.  If you only want to perform a distinct on a few then the general idea was right before, you just need to select just those two columns, not all four.  Use something like this instead of `Distinct`: `GroupBy(row => new{row.Col1, row.Col3}).Select(group => group.First())`

Comment: okay will do and what should i do to get the missing data to display, just displaying 4 rows. kinda in a pinch

Comment: @user1063280 Can't see any reason for that.  Odds are you're not reading the proper file, or a bunch of the records are all duplicates.

Comment: Reading the right file, will look into it, thank you so much bro. You have a great day!!